# Docker is not running ... failed

Tags: docker, service, dockerfile

I am running following commands:

```
docker run --name myjenkins -u root -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --privileged vaish

docker exec -it myjenkins vaish

service docker start

service docker status
```

output is [FAIL] Docker is not running ... failed!

Note: I have installed docker via dockerfile 
Note: my application is a set of docker containers

when i check service docker status on my host machine it is active(running )but the problem is from inside container!

Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
ENV JENKINS_SLAVE_AGENT_PORT '50000'
USER $USER
WORKDIR /var/jenkins_home/workspace/pipelineDemo@script
ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV
RUN apt-get update
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y npm
RUN npm install -g npm
RUN apt-get install python3
RUN apt-get install --reinstall make
RUN npm install --global gulp-cli
RUN npm install --global gulp
RUN apt-get -y install g++

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install
RUN apt-get -y install apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
     curl \
     gnupg2 \
     software-properties-common
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y docker-ce

RUN curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.21.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins

USER jenkins
COPY Jenkinsfile /var/jenkins_home/workspace/pipelineDemo@script
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

when i dont have docker in my jenkins docker container and i run npm run install I get following logs: in order ro avoid these error i had to install docker and docker compose in my jenkins docker container

```
> /var/jenkins_home/workspace/pipelineDemo@script
> node tasks/down.js

✖ Command failed: docker-compose kill
/bin/sh: 1: docker-compose: not found


>/var/jenkins_home/workspace/pipelineDemo@script
> node tasks/build.js

 ✔ bundle admin
 ✔ bundle front-end
 ✖ build admin
   → /bin/sh: 1: docker: not found
 ✖ build bank-accounts
   → /bin/sh: 1: docker: not found
```

Note: on my host machine docker got installed with npm i and npm run install commands

Comment: You cannot run Docker inside a container. Please clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If you want to run docker inside a container (DIND), you are looking at something like this: https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind as base image

Comment: @Roland Weber I had to install docker in my container as I had an error "docker not found" when i did npm i from inside container

Comment: @Maksim Luzik I want run jenkins is there any better dind image to run jenkins?

Comment: @TakethatstepFurther I havent tried myself, but this may help you out: https://hub.docker.com/r/mesosphere/jenkins-dind/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could not make myjenkins container independent so I run it with --net=hots in docker run command so it is atleast working. not what i wanted to but ended up with this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I found a solution [here](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/):

When you start your Jenkins container use `-v` to hand the host's docker.sock to the container:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...
```

It might also be an issue that you run an root, while Jenkins is being run by user `jenkins`. I'd expect a different error though.

Here is my Jenkinsfile (I don't install `docker-compose`)

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins

USER root

RUN apt update && apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
RUN apt update && apt install -y docker-ce
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins

USER jenkins
```

I start the container with

```
docker run --name mycustomjenkins \
  -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 \
  -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock <IMAGE-ID>
```

That way I am able to use Docker agents in my Jenkins.

Comment: docker run --name myjenkins -u root -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --privileged vaish     this is my docker run command which includes what you mentioned but no luck!

Comment: @TakethatstepFurther right. Did not see that in the first place. You won&#39;t need `--privileged` by the way.

Comment: @TakethatstepFurther I added my full Dockerfile and run command. I think the may difference is that I add the `jenkins` user to `docker` group.

Comment: yes I did add jenkins user to docker group ,also updated my docker file still no luck!

Comment: @TakethatstepFurther well I can only tell you that the above setup works for me.

Comment: i could not make myjenkins container independent so I run it with --net=hots in docker run command so it is atleast working. not what i wanted to but ended up with this.